# Ударение в слове "родился"

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Как правильно говорить: "роди́лся" или "родился́"? Этот вопрос можно отнести и к другим подобным глаголам.

Comment: _Igor Govorushko: Этот вопрос можно отнести и к другим подобным глаголам_. === А какие глаголы Вы считаете _**подобными**_ разбираемому глаголу? Все глаголы с постфиксом _**-ся**_?

Comment: В принципе, да.

Answer (score 2):

Аванесов даёт два варианта, причем родилс**я** - первым. 
http://dazor.narod.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0507.htm

Впрочем, основной современной нормой, пожалуй, следует признать "род**и**лся", а "родилс**я**" - допустимой. Ударение на возвратный суффикс сейчас вообще устаревает во многих глаголах.
Зарва подтверждает.
http://dazor.narod.ru/russkie/slovari/russkoe-udarenie/russkoe-slovesnoe-udarenie-zarva_449.htm

Однако, в разговорной и народно-поэтической речи - "родилс**я**". В этом и подобных глаголах ударение на -ся в разговорной речи выглядит более естественно.

.- Ах ты, Теркин. Ну и малый.
И в кого ты удался,
Только мать, наверно, знала...
.- Я от тетки родился
(Твардовский)

Answer (score 1):

Во всех глагола на -ить ударение почти всегда остаётся на **и**. 
 *брИть-брИться-брИлся, курИть-курИться-курИлся, сторожИть-сторожИться-сторожИлся* и соответственно  *родИть-родИться-родИлся*.

Так вплоть до середины  ХХ века и было (*В лесу родИлась ёлочка*), сейчас возможны уже оба варианта.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [Викисловарю](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F), в личных формах прошедшего времени глагола "родиться" допустимы два варианта ударения.

Answer (score -1):

*Никто не знал, Россия вся

Не знала, крест неся привычный,

Что в этот день, такой обычный,

В России... Ленин родилс**я**!*

Д. Бедный. 22 апреля 1870 года

Comment: В 1870-м Бедный напророчил?

Comment: @shampar У этого стихотворения (части) два названия: "Никто не знал..." ("22 апреля 1870 года"). https://poembook.ru/poem/10073 и https://besedinpawel.ru/demyan-bednyiy-nikto-ne-znal/. Если Вы считаете, что необходимо было указать оба, - я это сделаю.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, Название (в конце цитаты) не должно выглядеть, как дата публикации. С числами — случай не рядовой, понятно. Кавычки, наверное, нужны. Или реальная дата в конце стиха.